# Can I block Chrome’s <textarea> drag-to-expand feature?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, google-chrome

In Chrome, the bottom right of `<textarea>` fields can be pulled to expand the text area. This has its advantages sometimes, but sometimes, it does not. (This discussion is for another time.)

What I want to know is how I can block this behaviour, if possible. I’m thinking something along the lines of some JS/jQuery dingus, but I don’t really know how Google programmed the feature.

Has anyone dabbled with this?

Comment: onresize: event.preventDefault(), return false;

Comment: @kirilloid: How will this appear to the user? Will there still be an icon in the bottom-right corner of `<textarea>` fields, that just doesn’t allow the user to do anything?

Comment: Don't know =) I do not even know, whether this sould work - just an idea. So, use CSS solution from answers.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Have you tried using CSS yet to stop this?

```
textarea {
  resize: none;
}
```

That should disable the drag-to-expand feature.

**Update**

You could also set this programmatically by using jQuery:

```
// CSS
textarea.no-expand {
  resize: none;
}

// jQuery
$('#my-text-area').addClass('no-expand');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I wasn’t aware of `resize`. That look like it should do the job. Thanks—all of you.

Comment: You could also do `#my-text-area { resize: none; }`.  In general I don't see the need to introduce JavaScript when you can easily achieve the same thing with only CSS.

Comment: @nelson I just thought I would mention the jQuery alternative in case he wanted to control the drag-to-expand feature programmatically.

Comment: I misunderstood the point you were trying to make.  Point taken.

Answer (score 6):

A bit late to the party, but here goes. The problem with the `resize: none` solution is that it's not valid CSS. This will not only not validate, but not work on other browsers and might break in future releases of Chrome. A different, valid solution would be:

```
textarea {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
}
```

Of course, you should adjust your sizes accordingly. Sure, this doesn't have the flexibility of `resize: none` (you can't just apply one style to all your `textarea`s on your page), so, in that regard, `resize: none` would be better. However, if it's possible for you to use this solution, you should.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way is to just specify 'resize: none' as a part of your style:

```
textarea {
    resize: none
}
```

See http://www.electrictoolbox.com/disable-textarea-resizing-safari-chrome for more details.